# Aggregate number of active students

Tags: sql-server

In SQL I've got a table with students:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Student]
(
  [Id] bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
  [ActiveFrom] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
  [ActiveUntil] [DATETIME] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now I want to show a bar chart how many students have been active in each month of the year. A student is active in a month if [ActiveFrom] is before or in that month and [ActiveUntil] is null or later or in that month.

I guess I need some kind of group by, but since a student can be active for months or years I got no idea how to get those numbers in one SQL command.

Sample input

```
INSERT INTO Student (ActiveFrom, ActiveUntil)  VALUES ('20181001', '20181231')
INSERT INTO Student (ActiveFrom, ActiveUntil)  VALUES ('20181101', '20190131')
INSERT INTO Student (ActiveFrom, ActiveUntil)  VALUES ('20181201', '20181231')
INSERT INTO Student (ActiveFrom, ActiveUntil)  VALUES ('20190101', '20190430')
```

Expected output

```
Month,   Activecount
2018-10, 1
2018-11, 2
2018-12, 3
2019-01, 2
2019-02, 1
2019-03, 1
2019-04, 1
```

Comment: Need sample input and expected output :)

Comment: What is your attempt here? You have enough reputation to know how to ask a question which we can actually answer. :)

Comment: 1. Generate a table of first days of months (12 records). 2. Left join to students on the obvious relation between these days and the students' activity dates. 3. Group by the first days of months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ReportStartDate DATE = '20180101'
    , @ReportEndDate DATE = '20191231'
; WITH MonthCounter AS
(
    SELECT 1 i 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i+1 i 
        FROM MonthCounter
        WHERE i < DATEDIFF(MONTH, @ReportStartDate, @ReportEndDate)
) 
, Months AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, i-1, @ReportStartDate) AS StartDate
        , DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, i, @ReportStartDate)) AS EndDate
    FROM MonthCounter
) 
SELECT mo.StartDate
    , mo.EndDate
    , COUNT(st.[Key]) AS ActiveStudents
FROM Months mo
    LEFT JOIN Student st ON DATEDIFF(DAY, st.ActiveFrom, mo.enddate) >= 0
        AND (st.ActiveUntil IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(DAY, mo.startdate, st.ActiveUntil) >= 0)
GROUP BY mo.startdate
    , mo.enddate
ORDER BY mo.startdate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Apologies for the convoluted month generating code, but I really tried to make it happen in a single SELECT query, and I couldn't find a much better method than the recursive CTE.

Pay attention to the comparison. To determine whether a student is active in a month, the record's ActiveFrom must start sometime BEFORE the END of the month, and it's ActiveTo must be some date on or AFTER the BEGINNING of the month.

Comment: A couple of `WHILE` loops looks like an awfully inefficient way to do this. There would be far better options; such as using a tally table.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. I've updated the answer to calculate months from the available data in the Student table

Comment: You still have a `WHILE` loop left in there though.

Comment: Just to populate the #Student table. It's not really part of the answer code, it's there to make the code testable. Hence my comments delineating that code block.

Comment: Nice! But the gaps are a problem. If there is no from in a given month it won't be in the result, even though there had been students active which started before the gap and ended after the gap. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: (for example for my test data the last line of results would be missing)

Comment: Good point @Sam, I had missed it. I have modified my answer again to use a recursive CTE instead of a pre-generated month/numbers table. –